# Accessing Parent Instance from Child Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, static, parent

I am writing a code that will simulate the Kerberos protocol in Java. I have a server class and a client class. But some content is static and other content is not, plus sockets, I'm mixed up to say the least. The details of the protocol I believe are arbitrary in this question.

I have a Server class, which calls a ServerThread class:

```
public class Server{

    public void someMethod(){ /* some code */ }

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
    }
}

public class ServerThread extends Thread{
    /* constructor (takes serverSocket from Server) */

    this.parent.someMethod();
    /* That would call someMethod() from the parent class Server instance
     * that instantiated this.
     */
    }
```

The part of the Server class that instantiates the ServerThread was given to me, I have to use it as is. The someMethod() method I wrote myself, that's the one I want to use from ServerThread. Is there a way to do this call the line of code that says this.parent.someMethod();? If I can, is there a way to access both classes from a single controller class, or does the static content vs. non-static content ruin that idea?

Comment: When is a `Server` instance allocated?

Comment: sorry, a Server is instantiated in Server's main method, right before the ServerSocket. That can be moved around. Any of this code can be moved around. The main method could be in a separate class if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you pass a reference to an instance of the `Server` to the `ServerThread` (via getter/setters or modifing the constructor)? If so, pass the reference and then you can call `server.someMethod()`, assuming `server` is the variable name.

If not, would your `someMethod()` make sense as a static method? If it is safe to make it a static method, you can do `Server.someMethod().`

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate a `Server` (presumably, only one of them), write it to a static field in `Server`.  Then you can access that field from anywhere, including `ServerThread`.

In `Server`:

```
static Server server; // the one true server in this application
```

In `Server.main`:

```
server = new Server();
```

In `ServerThread`:

```
Server.server.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Server extends Thread{

    public void someMethod(){ /* some code */ }

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
      //  ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    }
}

  class ServerThread extends Server{
    /* constructor (takes serverSocket from Server) */
public ServerThread(){
     super.someMethod();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a socket context class instance to pass to your thread - the one that contains the serverSocket etc - load it up with the server instance 'this' as well.  You can then easily call methods on it from your ServerThread.